# Need to run a Custom chef recipe to be run with sudo priviliges

Tags: chef-infra, recipe

I have to run a custom chef recipe for creating a directory under /ops, but I do not want to use root user for this. I have a user who has the sudo priviliges to create a directory manually

```
 sudo mkdir /ops/usr/apps  is working fine manually.
```

I have my recipe to create a directory as this:

```
 directory "#{node[:workspace]}" do
   owner "#{node[:user]}"
   mode "0775"
   recursive true
   action :create
 end
```

Can I simulate something similar to above manual command using sudo for my current user. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just run chef solo using sudo?

```
$ sudo chef-solo -c solo.rb -j solo.json
Starting Chef Client, version 11.4.0
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 1 resources
Recipe: demo::default
  * directory[/ops/usr/apps] action create
    - create new directory /ops/usr/apps
    - change mode from '' to '0775'
    - change owner from '' to 'mark'

Chef Client finished, 1 resources updated
```